# The squared-norm of the projection of a Gaussian vector onto an independent $d$-dimensional subspace is a $\chi^2_{d}$

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, gaussian-process

How we can prove that:

The squared-norm of the projection of a $N$-dimensional complex vector with i.i.d. unit-variance and zero mean Gaussian components onto an independent $d$-dimensional subspace is a $\chi^2_{d}$. This projection can be represented as $|v^* \,h|^2$, where $h$ is the Gaussian vector and $v$ is the vector in the direction of the projection.

Comment: Please double check your result. The correct conclusion is the projection is a $\chi_d^2$ random variable, and if the normal vector is not of mean $0$, then this chi-square random variable has noncentrality parameter.

Comment: Question edited. I think it is $\chi^2_{2d}$ and not $\chi^2_{d}$.

Comment: But the truth is $\chi_d^2$, think about the simplest case, project a standard normal random variable  $Z$ onto $\mathbb{R}^1$ (which means the projection is $Z$ itself), what is the distribution of $Z^2$? $\chi_1^2$ or $\chi_2^2$?

Comment: Please check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Relation_to_other_distributions).

Comment: What's your point? Did you consider my example carefully?

Comment: Just to say that in your case $Z^2$ has a $\chi_2^2$ distribution and not $\chi_1^2$

Comment: How many normal random variables do we have in my example? $1$ or $2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A mathematics-inclined proof, may need some background of linear algebra*

For clarity, let's assume the whole space is $\mathbb{R}^N$ for which we shall consider as an $N$ dimensional vector space and the subspace is $M$ with $\dim(M) = d \leq N$. Let $\{u_1, \ldots, u_d\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $M$, which may be extended to an orthonormal basis $\{u_1, \ldots, u_d, u_{d + 1}, \ldots, u_N\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Treat $X \sim \mathcal{N}_N(0, I)$ as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$, the projection of $X$ onto $M$ can be expressed as 
$$P_M X = \sum_{i = 1}^d (X^T u_i) u_i.$$

By orthogonality of $\{u_1, \ldots, u_d\}$, we have
$$\|P_MX\|^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^d (X^T u_i)^2.$$

Also note that for every $(u_1^T X, \ldots, u_d^T X)^T = (u_1^T, \ldots, u_d^T)^T X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$ by the orthogonality of $\{u_1, \ldots, u_d\}$ and the linear transformation property of normal random vectors, thus $X^T u_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and are mutually independent, consequently, by definition, 
$$\|P_M X\|^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^d(X^T u_i)^2 \sim \chi_d^2.$$

Comment: But in my case $X$ is  complex.

Comment: Mat, it is essential that you stipulate that in your question.  If $X$ is complex it certainly isn't "standard" in any conventional sense and "$N$-dimensional" becomes ambiguous: $N$ complex dimensions or $N$ *real* dimensions?

Comment: @whuber Question edited. Hope it is clear now. (N complex dimensions)

Comment: This answer is still valid: when it was written, the symbol "$N$" referred to the number of *real* dimensions. Now that you have changed the meaning, you have to read "$2N$" everywhere in place of "$N$" and "$2d$" in place of "$d$" in this answer.

Comment: "$N$-dimensional complex vector" is a weird wording, if you are talking about "complex", then the dimensionality is $2$, can't be others.